# Java Web SQL: No suitable driver found for jdbc, but driver is added in project and code works fine local

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, web, jdbc

I'm trying to build dynamic web project i  having problem with sql connection. I made connector with database but i can run it.

Here is my code:

```
package DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Connect {

private static Connection conn;
private static final String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/web_db";
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String username = "root";
private static final   String password = "1234";

public static void open() {
    try {
        //Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() {
    return conn;
}
public static void close() {
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    open();  
}  

}
```

Now when i run it on server i get error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/web_db
```

but i added jar to build path and it's located in WEB-INF folder and when i run this code as Java Application and not on server it works fine, i tried uncommenting

```
//Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
```

and then got:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

except that i tried replacing "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/web_db"; with "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_db"; i same error happened also here what i added is my pom.xml:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Btw i using ubuntu 19.04 and Eclipse EE 4.9.0 and mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar

Comment: Just a hint: By convention, package names should only contain lowercase letters(and dots, maybe dashes)

Comment: @dan1st i know, i created package and it stayed that way, gonna change it for sure, but i have bigger problem now :)

Comment: It might help changing the location of the dependency in your `pom.xml`. (Not `dependencyManagement` but `project/dependencies`)

Comment: i tried that meanwhile and i got missing artifact for mysql:mariadb-java-client:jar:2.4.4 Edit: fix dependency, same No suitable driver error

Comment: Do you use `org.mariadb.jdbc`:`mariadb-java-client` now?

Comment: Yes i do, and i works just fine until run it on server, also i never had a problem with it until now, i already used it in project before this.

Comment: If you get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`, then the driver is not on the runtime classpath. Having the driver in the `dependencyManagement`-section of your POM does not add it as a dependency to your project. It just defines which version to use if it is added as a dependency. This is likely the problem. Make sure it is added in the `dependencies` section that is directly in `project`.

Comment: i replaced mariadb driver with mysql driver and it work fine, thanks :)